# Desperately trying to make an email/newsletter subscription website

Tags: linux, php, email, wordpress, newsletter

A friend of mine has a unique connection within a particular industry where he finds awesome deals in his vertical. The kind of deals that people would pay to get notified on.

The workflow:

1. User signs up (free or paid) and chooses which categories or tags they want to be notified for.
2. Admin enters deal including title, tags/categories, post body etc.
3. Anyone who has opted to receive notifications for matching tags/categories gets an email with the post body.
   Super simple and straight forward, but I'm finding it difficult to point him in the right direction.
4. Ideally, their membership level (free or paid) would determine how quickly or at what cadence any deals went out to them, but that's more of a want than a need.

I actually don't even care if it's done in WordPress or it's a standalone script.

I would be eternally grateful to anyone who can help point me in the right direction.

Comment: What are you looking for? A ready-to-use web-app – or instructions on how to build one? Note this site recommends *software* – not [howtos](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185) or [manuals/tutorials](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185).

Comment: Hi. Have you now found something for this?

Comment: Ended up using Wordpress and the Newsletter plugin from Tribulant and it's awful. Still haven't found a better solution.